# MongoDB: aggregation framework $group, preserve ObjectdID with C#

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents of the following form (simplified):

```js
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("546534507a28ab1c646c7a12"),
  "Name" : "DataPack1",
  "Properties" : {
    "Location" : "Berlin",
    "Event" : "FreePractice1",
    "Car" : "car_Otto",
    "Driver" : "Otto",
    "RunNumber" : 0,
    "LapNumber" : 0,
    "LapTime" : 18.545993426137603,
    "LapType" : "Out",
    "TimeStamp" : ISODate("2014-11-13T23:08:42.522Z")
  },
  ...
}
```

I now want to group the datasets using some fields (e.g. "Location", "Event") and finding the minimum of some value, e.g. LapTime. That works pretty well with a corresponding AF pipeline, consisting of match, group and project stages.
My $group stage looks like this, for example:

```
var group = new BsonDocument
{ 
    { "$group", 
        new BsonDocument 
        { 
            { "_id", new BsonDocument 
               { 
                  { "Location","$Properties.Location" }, 
                  { "Event","$Properties.Event" } 
               } 
            }, 
            { "FastestLap", new BsonDocument 
               { 
                   { "$min", "$Properties.LapTime" } 
               } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
};
```

All pretty straightforward. What bothers me now is the problem that I sometimes need some meta information to the found minimum value, lets say in which lapnumber/runnumber it occured. So basically I need to preserve the document (or it's ID) which was the actual minimum.
More general, is there a mechanism to preserve the original document, which led to the aggregation result? I know I can use something like:

```
{
   "original": {"$push: "$$ROOT"}
}
```

but that again will yield all documents considered in the aggregation function, not only the one I'm interested in.

Is there a way to achieve this, or do I have to write some map-reduce functionality, with which I'm not familiar at all right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of approaching this problem is:

- Sort all the records in ascending order of their `Properties.LapTime`.
- Group based on the fields.
- Now the record with the fastest lap time will be on top in each group
  since all the records are in sorted order.
- So `$first:"$$ROOT"` will give you the record where the fastest `Laptime`
  was encountered.

The code in native `mongo` driver is as below. Kindly transform the syntax as applicable.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$sort:{"Properties.LapTime":1}},
{$group:{"_id":{"location":"$Properties.Location","event":"$Properties.Event"},
         "FastestLap":{$first:"$Properties.LapTime"},
         "fastestLapDocument":{$first:"$$ROOT"}}},
{$project:{"_id":0,"FastestLap":1,"fastestLapDocument":1}}
],{allowDiskUse :true})
```

Comment: This is a nice way of approaching this problem (similar to a solution in SQL), but I'm a little bit concerned about performance. In your "global sort" solution I may have to sort hundreds of thousands of documents first instead of grouping them first and sorting afterwards. Thanks anyways, I will use this solution until I find a better one ;)

Comment: If you index on `Properties.LapTime`, then the sort is part of the index and you won't incur a huge penalty for sorting tons of documents.